# Exim4 won't send message

Tags: exim, clamav

My exim4 don't send any message. The logs says

```
2011-03-09 15:59:57 1PxKrl-00038i-BT malware acl condition: clamd: ClamAV returned /var/spool/exim4/scan/1PxKrl-00038i-BT: lstat() failed: Permission denied. ERROR
```

I supose that clamav (running clamd) does'nt have access rights on the mentioned file, but clamav is in the same group as Debian-exim (running exim4). Even changing the folder permissions to a+rwx has no effect.

Any idea where to look for failure reason ?

Comment: Clamav shouldn't need to be in the same group as exim.  It should be in in its own group (clamav).

Comment: clamav is member of both: Debian-exim and clamav. I don't add this to /etc/group so i guess that comes from the install script. I mentioned this, because of posts on other sites regarding this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Directory permissions on /var/spool/exim4/scan should be 750, and owned by the exim user and its primary group (on my FreeBSD systems, these are mailnull and mail, respectively).

If your clamav user has Debian-exim as a supplementary group - that is, if Debian-exim is not its primary group, then you need "AllowSupplementaryGroups yes" in your clamd.conf (and clamd must be started by root).

Comment: Ok, putting clamav in Debian-exim as primary group and clamav as supplementary is working.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Centos 6.2 running exim4 with clamAV, solved it by adding clam user to the mail group.

```
# usermod -a -G mail clam
```